# Set OWIN Response Status Code

Tags: c#, owin

This should be simple, so I must be missing something basic. In my OWIN app, I want to have a catch-all that redirects to the homepage (index.html).

I see no way in the

```
public Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
```

method to return a response code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the OWIN specification you have to set

```
environment["owin.ResponseStatusCode"] = 200;
```

See http://owin.org/spec/owin-1.0.0.html#_3.2._Environment

Comment: Thanks. Funny thing is I tried that, but setting it to a string. Somehow never occurred to me to try a number...